# How to use centos:8 docker image run postgresql client?

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos8

In a centos 8 Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:8

RUN yum update -y && yum install -y openssh-server sudo && yum clean all
RUN rm -rf /run/nologin

EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

After start it, install postgresql client in the container

```
docker exec -it centos8 /bin/bash

dnf module enable postgresql:12
dnf install postgresql-server
postgresql-setup --initdb
```

Got an error

```
[root@centos8 /]# postgresql-setup --initdb
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
FATAL: no db datadir (PGDATA) configured for 'postgresql.service' unit
```

Check status

```
[root@centos8 /]# systemctl status postgresql
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

When run `psql`

```
[root@centos8 /]# psql
psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Why can't use `systemctl` service? How to install a Postgres client on it?

Comment: This setup sounds like you're trying to hand-configure a virtual machine, but in an interactive shell in a Docker container.  This isn't a typical use of Docker, particularly since anything you install will be lost as soon as the container exits.  This also isn't really a programming question but more of a Linux tooling question; the [help/on-topic] describes what topics are allowed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Systemd` not supported in docker container. So if you want to start `postgresql server` service, you will have to start it directly by execute the postgresql binary, just like [how official do](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/docker-entrypoint.sh#L288), also refers to its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/7bd41786539082857396f4d1b4f1cb326ebee8de/13/Dockerfile):

```
exec gosu postgres "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"
```

But, you mentioned next:

> How to install a Postgres client on it?

So, if you just want to install postgres client, you have already made it done: `psql` is the postgres client, no need to  start postgresql server:

```
[root@4234406b3e6c /]# psql --help
psql is the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.
```

Comment: I tried to run `psql` after installation, got an error as I updated my question. The `When run psql` part.

Comment: Of course, the postgresql server not start, so your client can't link to a server. This is not client issue, it's your server issue. Your question mentioned you need a client, so no problem for client, you could use this client to connect to an external postgresql server to verify your client is ok.

Comment: Do you mean run the command on the centos container? I tried and returned: `bash: exec: gosu: not found`.

Comment: I understood now. Thank you. If I connect to remote server by `psql [host]` should work.